# Writing multiple xml files from one xml

Tags: android, xml

I have an XML file that has the data for multiple pictures such as GPS coordinates, date/time, and some image data. Is there anyway using the android platform that I can create individual XML files for each picture's data as I need to eventually send these individual files together in a linked list. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
    <Placemark>
        <name> //picture 1 info <name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates> //gps 1 cords <coordinates>
        <Point>
    <Placemark>
    <Placemark>
        <name> //picture 2 info <name>
        <Point>
            <coordinates> //gps 1 cords <coordinates>
        <Point>
    <Placemark>
<Document>
```

I want it to look something like this:

```
File 1:
<Placemark>
<Name> //picture 1 info <name>
<Point>
    <coordinates> //gps 1 cords <coordinates>
<Point>
<Placemark>

File 2:
<Placemark>
<Name> //picture 2 info <name>
<Point>
    <coordinates> //gps 2 cords <coordinates>
<Point>
<Placemark>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, parse all of the XML into individual elements and then write each element to an XML file? Is that a big deal?

Take a look here to figure out how to parse XML

[Java handling XML using SAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844458/java-handling-xml-using-sax)

Comment: Thanks for the response I am very new to Java/Android I have the file saved in a folder in the phone and that file has all the information of all the pictures. I want to be able to individually parse out that information into separate files from the one already created. Do you think think I could use this or some variation? http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/x-android/ (listing 11)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it in code by hand (though that certainly seems like the easiest answer for such a simple task) you could instead use an XSLT tranformation. Using a stylesheet might also make the process a little more flexible since you would just need to update the stylesheet instead of the code when/if the source formats change. My understanding based on another question ([XSLT support in Android 2.1 (and older)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508803/xslt-support-in-android-2-1-and-older)) is that Android 2.2 contains an XSLT transformer. You might also be able to use Saxon (http://saxon.sourceforge.net).

Since you're going from one XML file to many you would need to use the result-document directive from XSLT 2.0. Here's how: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-tipmultxsl/index.html.